# How to create Ctrl+f and ctrl+shift+f in vim?

Tags: vim, ripgrep

I am learning vim recently as i have to use vim in some restricted machines. As i am a vscode user, I would like to find <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> equivalent to do string search

```
Ctrl+f will search within the file

ctrl+shift+f  will search in all the files in the folder tree.
```

I added ripgrep , It search :Rg!  ,it always search in all files like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
Whether Rg can be used to search with the files? (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>).

Also how to add <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> mapping in vim

Comment: Vim can do both things out of the box without adding plugins and external dependencies. If you are going to use Vim for some time, I suggest learning how to use it (with `:help user-manual`) rather than trying to replicate your VSCode workflow.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with romainl, vim already has these function without any plugins. Just want to add some details.

Search string in current file is done by `/` in normal mode, see `:h /`, `:h pattern.txt`.

Search string in many files may be done by vimgrep command, see `:h :vimgrep`.

Also you may find useful [vim fzf plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim), it uses ripgrep you already installed and does much more.

Of course you can do mappings on `Ctrl-F` and `Ctrl-Shift-F`, but it will override builtin vim command, so I don't recommend to do it.

```
map <C-F> /
map <CS-F> :vimgrep /
```

See `:h map.txt`

Answer (score 0):

To add on what [@Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898116/dmitry) stated in their answer (regardless of whether or not one should), while you can map `Ctrl-F` to search, vim doesn't support detection of `Ctrl` vs `Ctrl-Shift` keybinds so an alternative would have to be used. One such alternative would be using `Ctrl-Alt-F` instead:

```
map <C-f> /
map <C-M-f> :vimgrep /
```

Or (for compatibility depending on how your terminal treats the Alt key):

```
map <C-f> /
map <Esc><C-f> :vimgrep /
```

---

Edit: Thanks to [@Baczek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38749/baczek) for mentioning in a comment, there's an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631242) that shares how to achieve such 'impossible' mappings in some contexts (I haven't tested its solutions myself).

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631241/mapping-otherwise-conflicting-or-unmappable-keys-in-terminal-vim for options on how to make the impossible sort of possible.